# Browers (Chrome, Safari,Firefox) can't see files after OSX is upgraded to Maverick

Tags: macos, browser, finder, maverick

Everything work well, until I decide to upgrade my OSX. I tried logging in and Out as forums suggested.

But Browsers can't see any single file from finder.Using finder Normally is okay.

[image]